# create zip file in php and rename each file before add

Tags: php, zip

i am using below code to create zip of mp3s. i am able to create zip using this successfully. but how can i rename each file before making zip...

```
    # define file array
    $files = array(
      'http://google.com/images/logo.png',
      'http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/53/Wikipedia-logo-en-              big.png/220px-Wikipedia-logo-en-big.png'
     );

     # create new zip opbject
     $zip = new ZipArchive();

     # create a temp file & open it
     $tmp_file = tempnam('.','');
     $zip->open($tmp_file, ZipArchive::CREATE);

     # loop through each file
     foreach($files as $file){

        # download file
        $download_file = file_get_contents($file);

        #add it to the zip
        $zip->addFromString(basename($file),$download_file);

    }

    # close zip
    $zip->close();

    # send the file to the browser as a download
    header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=download.zip');
    header('Content-type: application/zip');
    readfile($tmp_file);
```

Comment: Why not simply change the first parameter in `$zip->addFromString(basename($file),$download_file);`?

Comment: Is it to any certain pattern of the name for the zip? or will the zipfile have the same name as the mp3s?

Comment: no files in zip will not have same name as mp3s

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [renameName](http://php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.renamename.php) after the addFromString method line:

```
$zip->addFromString(basename($file), $download_file);
$zip->renameName(basename($file), 'nicename.mp3');
```

Comment: Thanks @william janoti .. thats what exactly worked for me i tried addfiles method but it didn't worked also...Thanks again..

Answer (score 1):

I did this and it worked. Hope this will help.

```
$filename = "New_File_Name.pdf";
$zip->addFromString( $filename,  file_get_contents($path));
```