# zip renameName function is not renaming files in sub directories

Tags: php, zip, renaming

I am compressing directories and sub directories using PHP zip library. Everything is working fine except renaming files under sub directories. This code is renaming the files successfully in root directory

```
$zip->addFromString(basename($file), $download_file);
$zip->renameName(basename($file), 'nicename.mp3');
```

but it is not renaming files in sub directory. Can anybody assist please ?

I have taken this code from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35863423/create-zip-file-in-php-and-rename-each-file-before-add)

Comment: "I am compressing directories and sub directories" ....yet you're using ZipArchive::addFromString(). Is there a (good) reason for that?

Comment: I have used Ammar Qala code from
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1334613/how-to-recursively-zip-a-directory-in-php

Comment: My objective is
1. Create unique download folder for each user **Done**
2. Zip folders / sub folders and files **Done**
3. Rename files **Working for root but not working for sub folder**
4. Download the zip folder **Done**

This is what I have so far
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1P8majqQF3VoChHxDty84vRX6UkTF4fuHqJcbQzNMVE8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Why do you provide the "wrong" name in the first place? Just add the files via [::addFile](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/ziparchive.addfile.php) and provide the name you want the entry to have within the archive as the second parameter (no need the rename it afterwards).

Comment: I am storing the name as timestamp i.e 1465467856.jpg in DB. I want user to see the proper name of file if he downloads. Okay I try addFile. Thanks.

Comment: It looks like addFile has done the trick. Thanks.